# Behavior of akka pub-sub when no subscriber is registered

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

We are planning to use akka [pub-sub](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html) in our project. I have the following 2 queries reg. the akka pub-sub behavior.

1. What if the Publisher starts sending the messages before any actor has subscribed. What will happen to those messages that were published before any subscriber came to existence. Will those be discarded silently ?
2. What if the subscriber actor dies?[There are no subscribers at all] Will the messages sent by the Publisher gets accumulated somewhere or will it be discarded by the pub-sub system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message routing is decided on the spot: no subscribers, no sending. Buffering messages arbitrarily within the toolkit will only lead to surprising memory outages. If you want to buffer you will have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If no one is subscribed, then the messages aren't caught. But if you set things up right, that won't be an issue.

For the second question, it depends what you mean by it dying. Actor death is where the actor is gone for good. Which is different from an actor failing and being restarted. If the actor is restarted using fault-handling in its supervisor, it preserves its mailbox so nothing is lost. Only if the actor completely died (not restarted), will it lose its mailbox.

So, with a good fault-handling scheme, you can preserve your messages across actor failure for most use-cases. Just keep your listeners higher-up in the actor heiarchy and push all risky things that are likely to fail such as I/O down to the bottom. Look into the error kernel pattern to see what I mean. That way, failure usually won't climb high enough for you to be losing mailboxes.

Since its just a restart, all messages it is subscribed for will still end up in its mailbox and be waiting for it.